# How do I stop playing a sound effect with SpriteKit and Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I'm writing a storybook app for my niece and I have a question about SpriteKit. I'm trying to set it so that there are different types of audio that play.

1. Background music that loops (AVFoundation)
2. Narration that plays when on a new page, or when you press the narrate button to replay the narration (SKAction)

My problem is that the narration will play on top of each other if the user changes the page, or if the user plays the replay narration button. So it ends up sounding like two people talking over each other.

How can I stop all narrations that are playing when a new narration is triggered?

I can't find any relevant help on the internet. I've seen some posts saying us AVFoundation, but from my understanding (albeit limited) that seems more for the background music and can only have one track playing.

Am I misinterpreting the documentation? Can someone help me answer this problem?

```
import SpriteKit
```

import AVFoundation

class Page1: SKScene {

```
// MARK: Touch handling

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        println("\(location)")

        //checks if someone touched the menu button
        if menuButton.containsPoint(location) {
            println("Play story with sound!")
            settings.setInProgress()
            goToPauseMenu()
        }

        if soundButton.containsPoint(location) {
            println("Play story with sound!")
            settings.setInProgress()
            runAction(playNar)
        }

        //checks if someone touched the forward button
        if pageForward.containsPoint(location) {
            println("Next Page!")
            settings.setInProgress()
            nextPage()
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your readings suggesting use of AVFoundation are good advice. I wouldn't characterize AVFoundation as just for background music though.

Yes, you can only play one stream at a time with an AVAudioPlayer instance, but you can have multiple instances of AVAudioPlayers playing different (or the same) streams all overlapping if your needs require it.  SpritKit's audio actions, relative to AVFoundation's controls, are so extremely limited that they're almost useless for all but the most basic requirements.

I have found myself, early in a project utilizing SKActions for sounds, but inevitably I need finer grained control of my audio (i.e. volume control, stopping it mid playback, etc..) and end up utilizing AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: Yes the SKAction is meant for, word for word from the documentation, "Playing simple sounds."  For example, pew pew pew goes the lazer blaster.  You'll want to use AVFoundation for actual control.

Comment: HI PixelCloudSt. You're absolutely right! I'm kind of a newbie at this, so I thought we could only have once instance total. I guess I missed out on the definition of instance... In any case your advice is spot on. and I realized my error. Thanks a lot for helping answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop sounds effects with sprite kit actions,  what you need to do is add a child node to your main node,  have the child node play the audio sound,  then pause the child node itself